# How to check a date (in UTC format) is 48 hours before today date

Tags: java, date

I tried to convert the new today's date object to UTC. But no luck since new date object is always in local time zone. I have been trying to verify two dates using 'before' method. date1 is in UTC format. date2 is today.

### The below code always prints the today's date object in local time zone.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String todayStr = sdf.format(new Date());// This string is in UTC. But I need date object in UTC.

        try {
            System.out.println(sdf.parse(todayStr));// This is still printing in local time zone.
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I think date comparisons normalise to UTC time anyway, so you shouldn't have anything to worry about

Comment: @ne1410s I'm sorry, I am not able to get what you are trying to say. can you please eloborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Date` object isn't in any time zone - it's just a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. The Unix epoch is typically described in terms of UTC (namely midnight at the start of January 1st 1970) but it's really just a point in time.

To get the point in time 48 hours before "now", you can use something like:

```
Date earlier = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(48));
```

You can compare that with any `Date` object to see which occurred earlier in time - again, with no reference to any particular time zone.

(This isn't an easily testable solution, admittedly - I prefer to abstract `System.currentTimeMillis()` behind a `Clock` interface, so that I can test with a fake clock set to whatever time I want.)

Unless you *need* a string representation, ignore it - as soon as you want a string representation, you need to think about both which calendar system and time zone you're interested in.

Note that you talk about "today's date" in the question - if you mean the start of a particular day, then the time zone *is* relevant, and you'll need to do more work.

Finally, I'd suggest that if you possibly can, you use either `java.time.*` from Java 8, or [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) instead of `java.util.Date` etc. The first two are both *much* better APIs than the last.

> The below code always prints the today's date object in local time zone.

Yes, that's because `Date.toString()` uses the local time zone. That's just what it (unfortunately) does, and it doesn't mean that the `Date` object is "in" the local time zone.

Comment: +1 Highly comprehensive. And not even related to mid-twenties Singapore. That's my fave :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Thanks for good explanation. It makes sense. Just want to try with below approach. I am not sure whether my approach works or not. I am just trying now 1. convert date(in UTC) to gregorian calendar and get date object 2. convert the today's date to gregorian calendar and get the date object 3. verify which date is before.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I tried with the below line of code.                    Date earlier = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(48));      This ' earlier' date object is always print in local time zone.

Comment: I am trying with Joda Time.

Comment: @KishorePaparthi: Yes, if you convert a `Date` to a `String` it will always use the local time zone. That's just what `toString()` does though - it doesn't represent the value in the `Date` itself. It's not at all clear to me why you'd want to do anything with `GregorianCalendar` - if you've got two `Date` objects, you can tell unambiguously which occurred first (or whether they're equal).

Answer (score 0):

See the [correct answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25690076/642706) for details.

## Yesterday and Day Before

Your requirement is unclear, but it seems you want to test if the target date-time string represents a date-time that lies within the 48-hour period before the beginning of today as defined by UTC time zone. In other words, yesterday or day before.

## Avoid `java.util.Date`

Avoid using the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java. They are notoriously troublesome. Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time). Both libraries have a date-time class that knows its own assigned time zone, unlike java.util.Date.

## Half-Open Span Of Time

And both libraries have classes to represent a span of time. Comparisons are done by the "Half-Open" approach where the beginning is inclusive and the ending exclusive. So your two-day period is defined as the first moment of day-before-yesterday (inclusive) and running up to, but not including, the first moment of today (exclusive).

## ISO 8601

Your string format is defined by the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Both Joda-Time and java.time use ISO 8601 for defaults in parsing and generating strings. So they have a built-in formatter to parse your string. Merely pass the string.

## Immutable Objects

Joda-Time uses [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Rather than modify ("mutate") an existing object, a new object is instantiated with values based on the original. The reason is for [thread-safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

## Joda-Time

Here is some example code in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4.

```
DateTime target = new DateTime( "2014-01-02T03:04:05.789Z", DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime nowUtc = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime today = nowUtc.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime dayBeforeYesterday = today.minusDays( 2 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
Interval interval = new Interval( dayBeforeYesterday, today ); // Half-Open.
boolean hit = interval.contains( target );
```